# C# Complex Tree - Component Data Structure

Tags: c#, tree

I'm struggling with a small problem: I need a TreeDataScructure. So what I mean is: I have a base class which holds a list of (lets call it RootObject). And all of these RootObjects have RootObjects children which can have children by themselves etc.. And to all of the RootObject you can add different types of components.

I tried it like this:

Base class:

```
RootObject[] Roots;

RootObject class:

RootObject Parent;
RootObject[] Childs;
IGenericComponent[] Components;
```

The problem is: when I for example need to get all components in the Base class I get a stackoverflow because looping through each Root and their children takes a long time. The second problem is serializing. It would be hard to serialize it because some components use um-managed memory. My second approach was to make a list of Roots and Components in the base class and then just give an index as Parent and children, which one can access is from the list. But that got very confusing soon.

Does anybody know a good, fast and easy way to a TreeStructure like that?

PS: Here is all my code to achieve this:

```
//These structs are like indexes to the list in the base class
public struct ScoAutoStride : IAutoStride<Sco> 
{
    public int Index { get; internal set; }
    public bool IsValid { get => KerboEngine.Scenery.SceneryObjects.Contains(KerboEngine.Scenery.SceneryObjects[Index]); }

    public Sco Get()
    {
       return KerboEngine.Scenery.SceneryObjects[Index];
    }

    public void Set(Sco newValue)
    {
        KerboEngine.Scenery.SceneryObjects[Index] = newValue;
    }
}

public struct CompAutoStride : IAutoStride<ScoComponent>
{
    public int Index { get; internal set; }
    public bool IsValid { get => KerboEngine.Scenery.SceneryObjectComponents.Contains(KerboEngine.Scenery.SceneryObjectComponents[Index]); }

    public ScoComponent Get()
    {
        return KerboEngine.Scenery.SceneryObjectComponents[Index];
    }

    public ScoComponent<T> CorrectGet<T>() where T : class
    {
        return (ScoComponent<T>)Get();
    }

    public void Set(ScoComponent newValue)
    {
        KerboEngine.Scenery.SceneryObjectComponents[Index] = newValue;
    }
}
//Components:
public abstract class ScoComponent
{
    public Type ChildType { get; internal set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;

    public ScoComponent() { }
}

public class ScoComponent<T> : ScoComponent where T : class
{
    public T RawClass { get; set; }

    protected void InitThis(T value)
    {
        RawClass = value;
        ChildType = value.GetType();
        Name = ChildType.Name;
    }

    public ScoComponent() : base() { }
}
//Root object:
public class Sco
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "NULL";

    public ScoAutoStride Parent { get; internal set; }

    public List<ScoAutoStride> Childs { get; internal set; }

    public List<CompAutoStride> Components { get; internal set; }

    public object Tag { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;

    public bool Popped { get; set; } = false;

    public const int MaxChilds = int.MaxValue;

    public g_Vec3 Position { get; set; }

    public g_Quatr Rotation { get; set; }

    public g_Vec3 Scale { get; set; }
}
```

The base class:

```
public class Scenery
{
    public string Name { get; internal set; }
    public List<Sco> SceneryObjects { get; internal set; }
    public List<ScoComponent> SceneryObjectComponents { get; internal set; }
    public int ScoStride { get; private set; } = 0;
    public int CompStride { get; private set; } = 0;

    public Scenery() { }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you did so far.

Comment: When you say 'get all components in the base class', I don't see any code for that. With a stack overflow it's likely that your algorithm has an error, or there's an issue with the content of your data e.g. Could a `RootObject` appear in its own children (or grandchildren etc)?

Comment: No it cant. I didnt post all the code there are static helpers for that - but its basically looping throught each object and getting the components then throught the children getting the components etc...

Comment: How many components are you expecting the tree to contain? thousands? millions? How many levels deep is the tree? thousands? millions?

Comment: I would suggest to create a base class with two components: List<MyComponentType> Items and List<MyType> Children; Then based on this, you can have as many components and childrens as you want, creating a Tree type structure.

Comment: @Rook maybe around 500-10000 - it will be my new scenry hierarchy structure for my engine.

Comment: With only 10000 items, you should absolutely not be getting stack overflows with a recursive tree traversal, unless your tree is totally unbalanced in a frankly weird way (eg. your tree looks more like a list). As rbennet suggested, the problem is very likely in the code you haven't shared yet, and if you're totally sure that your tree can't have loops in it then it must be in your traversal algorithm.

Comment: Ok, i will rewrite my old one :) Ill close thic question u can write an answer i will accept it!

Comment: I'd have thought it would be easier to share your code here ;-) But I'll stick my comment down as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only dealing with around 10000 items, then your tree shouldn't be very deep (a perfectly balanced binary tree of this size is 14 levels deep, for example) and so you should absolutely not be getting stack overflow errors unless:

1. your tree is really a list (eg. totally unbalanced, with every node having a single child, 10000 levels deep)
2. your tree is really a directed cyclic graph (where an object can appear as a descendent of itself, so traversal will never terminate)
3. your tree traversal algorithm is broken.

You've said that (2) can't happen, and (1) would probably be obvious to you, so the problem seems to lie in your tree traversal code that you haven't shared with us.